# XPath find text according last word in the string

Tags: xpath, substring

I need to find the whole text according last word in the string. I have something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style='white-space:nowrap;'>
      <a href=''>test</a>
    </td>
    <td>any text</td>
    <td>text text texttofind</td>
    <td>Not Available</td>
    <td class='aui-lozenge  aui-lozenge-default'>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style='white-space:nowrap;'>
      <a href=''>test</a>
    </td>
    <td>any text</td>
    <td>text text texttofind2</td>
    <td>Not Available</td>
    <td class='aui-lozenge  aui-lozenge-default'>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style='white-space:nowrap;'>
      <a href=''>test</a>
    </td>
    <td>any text</td>
    <td>text text texttofind3</td>
    <td>Not Available</td>
    <td class='aui-lozenge  aui-lozenge-default'>text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I need to find whole text vallue according last word *texttofind*
`<td>text text texttofind</td>`

I cant use contains, because it will find multiple values. I need something like ends-with but I am using xpath 1.0.
I tried something like this, but I am not sure what is wrong because it is not working

```
//tr[substring(., string-length(@td) 
                          - string-length('texttofind') + 1)  = 'texttofind']
```

or maybe it would be better to use matches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there; try changing your xpath expression to

```
//tr//td[substring(., string-length(.) 
                          - string-length('texttofind') + 1)  = 'texttofind']
```

and see if it works.